# Getting first subnode of given parent node when subnode count can change

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm querying a web API and getting a JSON as response which I'm parsing with JSON.NET. The structure of the resulting JSON can vary. A certain node (called items in example) can contain zero, one or multiple sub nodes (called item). Have a look at my example code and you'll see three different JSON data under case1, case2 and case3.

I'm trying to find a simple solution to cover each case and access some data from the first item (ie "title" and "artist")

If there are multiple *item* nodes, then I'm always only interested in the first item. Hence the hardcoded *item[0]* because `JSON.Parse()` will return an indexed object here.

But if there is only a single *item* node, `JSON.Parse()` returns an object without any index. And accessing data via `item[0]` wouldn't work. You have to use `item` instead.

My question is relatively simple: Is there an elegant way to access the first sub note of a given parent node if there is only one *or* multiple sub nodes?

My current workaround (10 additional lines of code) looks cumbersome. In comparison you'll get the same functionality in Powershell with a single line:

```
$title  = @($json.ItemSearchResponse.Items.Item)[0].ItemAttributes.Title
```

Here `@()` is used to convert a single item to an array so all possible JSON cases are covered when using the index `[0]`. But in C# converting a JObject to an array with `.ToArray()` works differently.

---

You can copy+paste this code into a Windows console test project and run it. Switch through my different JSON examples via `var json = case2;` and see the difference.

Any ideas? Maybe JSONpath? Converting to array/list/IEnumerable? `SelectNodes` or `Select` instead of `SelectNode`?

## Working example in C-Sharp (needs a reference to JSON.NET)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace testspace
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {           

            // JSON example data
            // case with one "Item".  Access token via "Item" (no index)
            JObject case1 = JObject.Parse(@"{
                          'ItemSearchResponse': {
                            'Items': {
                              'TotalResults': '1',
                              'Item': {
                                'ASIN': 'B00J6VXXXX',
                                'ItemAttributes': {
                                  'Creator': 'MyArtist1',
                                  'Genre': 'pop-music',
                                  'ReleaseDate': '2014-06-09',
                                  'Title': 'MyTitle1',
                                  'TrackSequence': '10'
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }");

            // case with multiple "Item"s. Access token via "Item[0]" (with index)
            JObject case2 = JObject.Parse(@"{
                          'ItemSearchResponse': {
                            'Items': {
                              'TotalResults': '2',
                              'Item': [
                                {
                                  'ASIN': 'B001FAXXXX',
                                  'ItemAttributes': {
                                    'Creator': 'MyArtist1',
                                    'Genre': 'pop-music',
                                    'ReleaseDate': '2007-04-17',
                                    'Title': 'MyTitle1',
                                    'TrackSequence': '7'
                                  }
                                },
                                {
                                  'ASIN': 'B00136XXXX',
                                  'ItemAttributes': {
                                    'Binding': 'MP3 Music',
                                    'Creator': 'MyArtist2',
                                    'Genre': 'pop-music',
                                    'ReleaseDate': '2007-04-17',
                                    'Title': 'MyTitle2',
                                    'TrackSequence': '7'
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        }");

            // case with no "Item"s. Should return empty/null strings when trying to access "item" data, and not throw an error 
            JObject case3 = JObject.Parse(@"{
                          'ItemSearchResponse': {
                            'Items': {
                              'TotalResults': '0',                            
                            }
                          }
                        }");


            // #######################################################
            //switch between different possible json data
            var json = case2; // <- switch between "case1", "case2", "case3" to see the difference


            //expected result for case1 and case2 should be "MyTitle1"
            // but this works only for first case - not for second case
            string result1 = (string)json.SelectToken("ItemSearchResponse.Items.Item.ItemAttributes.Title");
            Console.WriteLine("try 1: " + result1);


            // expected result for case1 and case2 should be "MyTitle1"
            // but this works only for second case - not for first case
            string result2 = (string)json.SelectToken("ItemSearchResponse.Items.Item[0].ItemAttributes.Title");
            Console.WriteLine("try 2: " + result2);             


            // ugly workaround I'd like to get rid off
            string result3 = null;
            if (json.SelectToken("ItemSearchResponse.Items.Item") != null ) {
                JToken item;
                if ((int)json.SelectToken("ItemSearchResponse.Items.TotalResults") == 1) {
                    item = json.SelectToken("ItemSearchResponse.Items.Item");
                } else {
                    item = json.SelectToken("ItemSearchResponse.Items.Item[0]");
                }
                result3 = (string)item.SelectToken("ItemAttributes.Title");
                // access more data like artist, release-date and so on
            }
            Console.WriteLine("workaround: " + result3);
            // #######################################################


            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

case #1 and case #3 are the same, as case #3 has no items, null is a valid array - no problem there. The problem is case #2, but this can be solved with JSON.NET custom parsers.

I will make the objects simpler, to make the whole code shorter. I am using JSON.NET, because it is everything you need. So here is my BigObject that contains zero, one, or more Items:

```
public class Item
{
  public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class BigObject
{
  [JsonConverter(typeof(ArrayItemConverter))]
  public List<Item> Items;
}
```

Note the decoration I made with my custom ArrayItemConverter:

```
public class ArrayItemConverter : JsonConverter
{
  public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
  {
    object retVal = (string)null;
    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
    {
      Item instance = (Item)serializer.Deserialize<Item>(reader);
      retVal = new List<Item>() { instance };
    }
    else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
    {
      List<Item> list = serializer.Deserialize<List<Item>>(reader);
      retVal = list;
    }
    return retVal;
  }

  public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

What I say here is that if I detect a start of an object (in JSON syntax there is '{'), I will deserialize a single Item and create a new List for it and put it there.

If I detect a start of an array ('[' in JSON), I will deserialize the array to the list.

Here are my tests:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string case1 = @"{
     ""Items"": {
         ""Value"":1
     }
  }";

  string case2 = @"{
     ""Items"": [
        {
         ""Value"":21
        },
        {
         ""Value"":22           
        },
     ]
  }";


  string case3 = @"{
  }";

  BigObject c1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BigObject>(case1);
  Console.WriteLine("c1 value = {0}", c1.Items[0].Value);

  BigObject c2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BigObject>(case2);
  Console.WriteLine("c2 value1 = {0}", c2.Items[0].Value);
  Console.WriteLine("c2 value2 = {0}", c2.Items[1].Value);

  BigObject c3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BigObject>(case3);
  Console.WriteLine("c3 items = {0}", c3.Items == null ? "null" : "non-null" );
}
```

The console output is:

```
c1 value = 1
c2 value1 = 21
c2 value2 = 22
c3 items = null
```